# Curtains lined with the same material: where should I put the seam?

Tags: sewing

I'm making some small curtains with both sides facing inside the house (they're for a cabin bed).  Normally the inside (fancy) fabric would be folded over and slightly larger than the lining fabric, so the edges are the nice fabric, the lining is smaller, and the seam on the lining side away from the fold.

When lining with the same fabric, should I do the same, or cut both pieces the same and have the seam at the fold?

(Apologies for poor terminology; I'm new to this)

Comment: Do whatever you think looks or works best for your own preferences and skills. There are no "curtain police" who are going to come arrest you for "doing it wrong." :)

Comment: @AllisonC true, but as a novice, if someone's found it looks better or is easier to sew one way I'd rather do that. TBH either looks easy enough (compared to the next project I have in mind)  that it shouldn't matter from that point of view that if there's a generally preferred way for looks I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will mostly view the curtain from one side, handle that as the 'side you look at in normal curtains', do have that side a bit bigger and fold the edges over to seem them.

On the other hand, if you will see the whole of the curtain from both sides and you will want both to look nice, two pieces of fabric the same size, put the good side on the good side and sew around the outside, I would leave either the top or the bottom open for now. Turn and top stitch just inside the edge.

Most likely you will do something in the top seam to hang the curtain. If you have the skills to do that with the two layers of fabric finishing it nicely at the same time, keep the top open.
Otherwise, close the top and keep the bottom open and 'only' top-stitch that closed. (You can even seam both sides individually and leave them open at the bottom, your call, if will fall better but is more likely to get out of shape.)

If the side seam is shorter or more out of sight you can use that as the last instead. You can play around quite a lot, as nobody but you will judge your quality of work.

Comment: ChrisH If I used terms you are not familiar with I am happy to explain more.

Comment: Just curious - why not start with 2 pcs the same size, put them back-to-back (wrong side out), stitch the sides, then turn it inside out (right side out) and press the seams flat to make them invisible at the edges?

Comment: I think the extra (top) stitching around the outside makes a stronger seam and a better fall, but it might be that your method is good enough.

Comment: That's very clear, thank you. I'll have to have a think, but as the edges will be quite visible, I'm inclined to go with the option in your 2nd paragraph, and finish at the top. I just have to get a good thread match for the top-stitching, with suitable shops closed at the moment.

Comment: @fixer1234 that was one of my original ideas, but I wasn't sure how flat it would go, so the top-stitching might be just what I need

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to intentionally make the outer fabric more visible on the inside.

> Normally the inside (fancy) fabric would be folded over and slightly larger than the lining fabric, so the edges are the nice fabric, the lining is smaller, and the seam on the lining side away from the fold.

This is the way to go for most lined pieces of clothing. Now, if you make the lining - let's say - 2 inches smaller and the outer fabric 2 inches longer, your seam would be on the backside of the curtain and show a strip of outer fabric next to the lining fabric. Depending on the colors and patterns of the fabric, this could create a very nice and decorative accent.

To assemble this:

1. Align one long edge of both fabrics, right sides facing each other.
2. First sew the long seam and either press it open (if both fabrics have the same weight) or press it over to the side of the lightweight fabric (if one is much lighter than the other).
3. Then align the top edges of the fabric, still right sides facing each other. Add your solution to hang the curtain at this stage. For example, if you want to add loops to hang the curtain, you put each loop between your both fabric layers and align the open end of the loop with the open end of the curtain.
4. Pin the short edges into this position and sew both sides, while leaving an openig to turn it over. Clip the corners, turn the curtain over (right sides out) and press the side seams. If the side seams don't lay flat, you might need to top stitch over them.
5. Lastly, if everything looks fine and straight, press the crease into the bottom edge of the curtain. This should be the last step because (depending on the fabric) it might be impossible to remove the crease again.

Comment: That would seem to be standard when lining with a different material. Here I've got the same fabric as I've effectively got 2 right sides of the finished curtain, so no accent stripes, just seams

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood your question. I assumed you have a different fabric as lining.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in your question, since both sides are the same fabric, “cut both pieces the same and have the seam at the fold”. It might be easier and will look solid once pressed. Tip: prewash the fabric it can shrink. And it will be easy to wash in the future.
Also, Folding the fabric in half makes sewing easier (like making a pillowcase) or sewing selvage to selvage, that makes it even easier.

[image: pillow case with right sides together]!

If you use clips to hang them, construct them as if they were a pillow case. Make the bottom hem, press, Pin the fabrics right sides together, sew up the sides, then the top. turn it inside out, press.
Have fun!
[close up curtain clips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6VQ7.jpg)

Comment: pic of pillowcase on sewing machine is sideways